# How can I insert the score into one table as an average of values from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

This my first query to insert the scores from the form:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Category(timing, musicality, technique, difficulty, performance_id)
      VALUES ('{$timing}', '{$musicality}', '{$technique}', '{$difficulty}','{$performance}')"
      ;
```

This works and it places the scores into a individual scores table, now im trying to take the average of these scores and put them into a table where the contestants information is located, I left a column blank for the scores to go into and heres the query I tried for that:

```
$query2 = "Insert into Contestants (score) select 
sum(timing + musicality + technique + difficulty)/(select count(timing)* 4 from Category where performance_id = '{$performance}')
From Category
WHERE performance_id = '{$performance}';";
```

Whats happening is, it is inserting the correct average score into the table that I want it to, in the correct field, but instead of updating the row based on the performance_id, it creates a new row. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try using the `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: If you want to update, use `UPDATE` Keyword.

Comment: Do you have `performance_id` column in the `Contestants` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE Contestants SET score = (select 
sum(timing + musicality + technique + difficulty)/(select count(timing)* 4 from Category where performance_id = '{$performance}')
From Category
WHERE performance_id = '{$performance}') 
WHERE performance_id = '{$performance}';";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as I need it to, really appreciate it.